# Once the ControlsLoop function is called, the playerState never changes and the while loop is always running

Tags: lua, fivem

Once the player enters a zone and the ControlsLoop function is called, the playerState never updates, but when the controlsLoop isn't called, the player state updates, unsure why.

**SOLVED**: Found the issue i wasn't using the CreateThread function is essential for running it asynchronously without blocking the main thread. This allows the script to continue handling events and state changes as expected.

Code:

```lua
local debugMode = true

ScriptFunctionality = {
  isInZone = false
  -- activeRobberyInfo = {}
}

ScriptFunctionality.InitScript = function()
  for i = 1, #Config do
    local robberyIndex = Config[i]
    local zone = BoxZone:Create(robberyIndex.vec3, 2.0, 2.0, {
      name = robberyIndex.name,
      heading = 0,
      debugPoly = debugMode,
    })

    --- @param playerState boolean
    zone:onPlayerInOut(function(playerState)
      ScriptFunctionality.isInZone = playerState

      if playerState then
        ScriptFunctionality.zoneInfo = robberyIndex
        print(("(DEBUG) Player is in the zone: %s"):format(robberyIndex.name))
      end

      ScriptFunctionality.ControlsLoop()
    end)
  end
end

ScriptFunctionality.ControlsLoop = function()
  while ScriptFunctionality.isInZone do
    ShowFloatingText(ScriptFunctionality.zoneInfo.vec3, "Hello there!")
    if IsControlJustReleased(0, 38) then
      print("(DEBUG) E Was pressed, usually used to start the robbery but this is still in development :)")
    end
    Wait(5)
  end
end
```

Well to be honest i haven't tried much  else, but i'll look into it, i just want a definitive answer as to why this is happening.